# Regex - Split the string on most right slash occurrence [Hive]

Tags: regex, string, hiveql

I want to split the path string based on the rightmost slash occurrence. The folders depths is variable - I can't know how many slashes I have. Is it possible to create the regex for this? I use it in HIVE queries for SPLIT function.

For example:

**original string**

```
/IP/backup_jun20_2017/proddb/application_profile/mth_end_dt=2016-10-31/000000_0
```

After split:

**string 1**:

```
/IP/backup_jun20_2017/proddb/application_profile/mth_end_dt=2016-10-31
```

**string 2**:

```
000000_0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this regex [`(.*)\/(.*?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/BiYQKW/1) or [`(.*)\/([^\/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/qrR5nr/1)

Which match two groups `(.*)` the first one before the last slash, the second group after the last slash you can get it like this `\/(.*?)$` or `([^\/]+)`

Comment: It is works fine for the bash regex, but I need it for SPLIT function in HIVE, sorry did not mention it in the question. In Hive id does not work. SPLIT does not cut the string to parts.

Comment: @OlegHmelnits I'm not familiar with hive but a quick search i find that split not use regex maybe using this can help you `regexp_extract('/IP/backup_jun20_2017/proddb/application_profile/mth_end_dt=2016-10-31/000000_0', '^(.*)\/([^\/]+)', 1) as result1
regexp_extract('/IP/backup_jun20_2017/proddb/application_profile/mth_end_dt=2016-10-31/000000_0', '^(.*)\/([^\/]+)', 2) as result2` if it work let me know?